# Name of a book series about a guy in a VR game with a traitor companion

Tags: story-identification

I've been trying to remember the name of the book and series for years. I'm pretty sure it's about a game that is like some kind of VR where the character is in the game and when they start they have to pick a companion. But the catch is that 1 companion is randomly designated as the traitor and will betray the main character. They pick a female companion and there seems to be a level of sentience and awareness to what is supposed to be an NPC, suggesting something else is happening. There also seems to be a bit of a romance between the main character and the female companion. Something happens to the main character's original progress and they have to restart and they pick the same companion, but she is assigned the traitor role the second time he picks her.

Comment: If someone posts a correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 7):

I believe this novel is *[Demons Don't Dream](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/15453)* (1992), from Piers Anthony's series about the magical land of Xanth.

Below is a short summary that I have edited from the novel's [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demons_Don%27t_Dream).

Dug, a Mundane, is transported in to the magic land of Xanth when he plays a computer game. The game consists of the player having a companion, who is usually a well known Xanth character, and being led through the magical world while defeating challenges along the way and eventually winning the prize of a magic talent. The catch with the companions is that there is a chance that your companion is false, required by the game's rules to cause Dug's ultimate downfall.
The game also has a way of becoming real to the player if Dug believes in magic.

Dug picks Nada Naga (A snake shapeshifter) as his partner. Dug is kicked out of the game twice; once temporarily, with the second ejection requiring him to restart from the beginning. He picks Nada to be his partner again but fails to remember that there is a chance that she will be a False Companion.

[image]

Comment: If so, it would be a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/171627/book-where-a-boy-and-girl-are-transported-into-a-fantasy-video-game/171639#171639